# Was tithing 10% required or encouraged by the early church?

Tags: church-history, early-church, tithe, 2-corinthians

I cannot find in the New Testament an obligation on Christians to tithe 10% of their income. Instead I read that it is up the individual to decide:

> [2 Corinthians 9:7 (NIV1984)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Corinthians%209:7&version=NIV1984)
>   Each man should give what he has decided in his heart to give, not reluctantly or under compulsion, for God loves a cheerful giver.

Is there a church tradition established by the early church to encourage everyone to tithe 10%?  What was the early church's view on tithing?

Comment: +1, everyone hears "tithe 10%", but I've never thought to check in the bible about that.. :)

Comment: "to tithe 10%" is a bit like saying "to quarter 25%" (i.e. it is a tautology). Is the question here "are they called to tithe?" or is it specifically the 10%?

Comment: @MarcGravell: the latter - is it 10%?

Comment: @Wikis the early Church is not the only basis for authority or thought in Christianity: it excludes nearly 1,800 years of thought ranging from Augustine to Thomas Acquinas on up to the modern era. For example as a Roman Catholic, I can't provide a complete answer to the doctrinal question if my hands are tied by saying I'm not allowed to use the full 2,000 years of Church tradition to answer it. It'd also rule out nearly every Protestant denomination (nearly all of which appear in the 16th century or later). Focusing just on what the early Church thought, however, is answerable.

Comment: Since you disagree with the edits (which is fine, I've rolled them back), I'm going to have to close this as Not Constructive.  Since this isn't asking about any particular doctrine or denomination, this question is too wide ranging as it stands.  [Please see this post on how to get your question reopened](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/690/what-makes-a-good-focused-question).

Comment: @Richard Perfectly good question, no less constructive than many on this site. Plenty of questions about practices that differ between denominations are allowed. Reopen.

Comment: Read as the historical question (i.e. what did the Early Church think), this is fine: that's what I read it as and answered to. Read as a doctrinal question (what is the current thought) is fine too, although a bit broad. But restricting a current doctrinal question to only allowing answers that are based on Early Church teachings is misguided: no Church restricts their doctrine to just pre CE 100-200 teachings.

Comment: @DJClayworth If you disagree with the quality standards, feel free to comment in one of the meta posts:  [The problem statement](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/680/can-we-reverse-the-trend-on-low-quality-posts); [The accepted solution](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/690/what-makes-a-good-focused-question).  If you can rally community support against these standards, we will gladly modify or remove these standards.  As it stands, however, these standards were agreed upon by the community.

Comment: Hi all - nice comments, appreciate the re-open votes. I haven't voted to re-open because I have to admit that I *think* Richard was right to close. Preferably I'd like to go back to his improved version and re-open. This is because I don't see how I can ask for a modern day interpretation without, as Richard stated above, either asking for either a doctrine or specifically about the early church... nice catch, Richard.

Comment: I honestly believe that both questions (the historical viewpoint and the modern day application) both have a place here.  I'd like to see both of these questions on this site.  However, a broad sweeping question that is asking about all doctrines is going to encourage debate and protracted discussions, which isn't ideal for the QnA format.

Comment: @Richard - but for the modern day version we'd have multiple questions: what do Catholics believe, Protestants, Evangelicals, Baptists, ... and all variations inbetween. Or is there a clever way around that?

Comment: Sure, you can ask for a comparison or a survey:  *"What are the different doctrines regarding tithing and what do these doctrines say?"*  There's only a handful of views, so I suspect that the answer to this will be succinct enough.  You can also use comparison: *"How do Southern Baptists, versus American Baptists, view tithing?"*  Either of these two questions ask for *doctrine* specifically.  They prevent answers that a purely opinion.

Comment: @Richard - for the time being, would you like to revert to your "early church" edits and re-open? Someone may take you up on your "modern church" question idea.

Comment: as a side note, when you look at how much was required of the nation of Israel, while there was a tithe, the additional offerings and mandates come out to ~21% (iirc) of one's income

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The word tithe itself [comes from the Old English *teogoþa*, meaning "tenth"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithe) - so technically, tithing is the giving of a tenth by definition. But of course that's not what you're asking!

The idea of giving a tenth comes from the Old Testament:

[Leviticus 27:30-33 (MSG):](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus%2027:30&version=MSG)

> "A tenth of the land's produce, whether grain from the ground or fruit
>   from the trees, is God's. It is holy to God. If a man buys back any of
>   the tenth he has given, he must add twenty percent to it. A tenth of
>   the entire herd and flock, every tenth animal that passes under the
>   shepherd's rod, is holy to God. He is not permitted to pick out the
>   good from the bad or make a substitution. If he dishonestly makes a
>   substitution, both animals, the original and the substitute, become
>   the possession of the Sanctuary and cannot be redeemed."

[Deuteronomy 14:22-29:](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy%2014:22-29&version=MSG)

> Make an offering of ten percent, a tithe, of all the produce
>   which grows in your fields year after year. Bring this into the
>   Presence of God, your God, at the place he designates for worship and
>   there eat the tithe from your grain, wine, and oil and the firstborn
>   from your herds and flocks. In this way you will learn to live in deep
>   reverence before God, your God, as long as you live. But if the place
>   God, your God, designates for worship is too far away and you can't
>   carry your tithe that far, God, your God, will still bless you:
>   exchange your tithe for money and take the money to the place God,
>   your God, has chosen to be worshiped. Use the money to buy anything
>   you want: cattle, sheep, wine, or beer—anything that looks good to
>   you. You and your family can then feast in the Presence of God, your
>   God, and have a good time.
>
> Meanwhile, don't forget to take good care of the Levites who live
>   in your towns; they won't get any property or inheritance of their own
>   as you will.
>
> At the end of every third year, gather the tithe from all your
>   produce of that year and put it aside in storage. Keep it in reserve
>   for the Levite who won't get any property or inheritance as you will,
>   and for the foreigner, the orphan, and the widow who live in your
>   neighborhood. That way they'll have plenty to eat and God, your God,
>   will bless you in all your work.

But, as you rightly say, in the New Testament we are instructed to give what we can, or to give whatever we feel is the right amount. Working out what that right amount is, is of course different for each person and therefore many have sought guidance on what the correct amount should be.

The passages in Leviticus and Deuteronomy don't just give an instruction but give some reasoning too; by giving ten per cent of everything in worship to God, we still have enough left over to live comfortably on.

When we look at Jesus' teaching on giving, he calls us to give much more than 10 per cent:

[Matthew 19:21 (MSG)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2019:21&version=MSG)

> "If you want to give it all you've got," Jesus replied, "go sell your
>   possessions; give everything to the poor. All your wealth will then be
>   in heaven. Then come follow me."

[Mark 12:40-42 (MSG)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%2012:40-42&version=MSG)

> Sitting across from the offering box, he was observing how the crowd
>   tossed money in for the collection. Many of the rich were making large
>   contributions. One poor widow came up and put in two small coins—a
>   measly two cents. Jesus called his disciples over and said, "The truth
>   is that this poor widow gave more to the collection than all the
>   others put together. All the others gave what they'll never miss; she
>   gave extravagantly what she couldn't afford—she gave her all."

On that basis, we might view ten per cent as the *minimum* we should be giving. The church I attend (a "New Church") teaches that we should give what we feel is the right amount, 2 Corinthians 9:7 indicates - but as a guideline 10% should be a starting point. (My church also practices what it preaches - 30% of income is given away to other projects and charities).

Comment: Actually, the question was never about modern church doctrines.  I've edited the question to more clearly show that he is interested in the historical perspective of the biblical and early church.

Comment: @Richard Thanks, I'll reword that bit of my answer

Comment: @Richard, Waggers: I think I need help here. I was going to reply that Richard's statement was, *"not true; my intention is to ask about modern church practice - does 10% apply to us, today? What does the Bible say and, if the Bible is silent, was there a precedent set by the early church?"* However, I don't see how I can ask for a modern day interpretation without, as Richard stated above, either asking for either a doctrine or specifically about the early church... nice catch, Richard.

Comment: @Waggers you make a good argument that the NT does not specify an amount, and that the tithing rules no longer apply, you then completely spoil it by making up your own rule - that 10% is the minimum.

Comment: @DJClayworth There's a difference between a rule and a guideline; perhaps I haven't made it clear that the 10% minimum is a "best practice" / rule-of-thumb type thing as opposed to the hard-and-fast rule that existed before. I'll think about how I can better express that in my answer, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Wikis I'm glad I didn't have completely the wrong end of the stick!

Comment: @Waggers, shouldn't a church tithe 100% of income to other projects and charities? What is the remaining 70% used for?

Comment: @pacerier Paying staff, accommodation costs, tax, insurance, maintenance, stationary, teaching/learning materials, running the church's own projects, a community fund to help those in need, etc

Answer (score 13):

Giving everything (or even 10%) is an [evangelical counsel](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/04435a.htm): it's not required for salvation. As you quote, the early Church only directed its members to give what they could, not a minimum amount (much less everything). Paul even writes, just before the passage you quote, in [2 Corinthians 5:5](http://www.usccb.org/bible/2corinthians/9:5):

> So I thought it necessary to encourage the brothers to go on ahead to you and arrange in advance for your promised gift, so that in this way it might be ready as a bountiful gift and not as an exaction.

And while I'm no Biblical scholar, Matthew 19:21 ought to be read in context. Just preceding this verse is [Matthew 19:16-17](http://www.usccb.org/bible/mt/19:16):

> <sup>16</sup>Now someone approached him and said, “Teacher, what good must I do to gain eternal life?”
>   <sup>17</sup> He answered him, “Why do you ask me about the good? There is only One who is good. If you wish to enter into life, keep the commandments.”

That's it: the only thing *required* for salvation is to keep God's commandments, which Jesus enumerates in [Matthew 19:18-19](http://www.usccb.org/bible/mt/19:18): poverty or charity is not listed among them.

Then taking the [verses *after* and including Matthew 19:21](http://www.usccb.org/bible/mt/19:21):

> <sup>21</sup>Jesus said to him, “If you wish to be perfect, go, sell what you have and give to [the] poor, and you will have treasure in heaven. Then come, follow me.”
>   <sup>22</sup>When the young man heard this statement, he went away sad, for he had many possessions.
>   <sup>23</sup>Then Jesus said to his disciples, “Amen, I say to you, it will be hard for one who is rich to enter the kingdom of heaven.
>   <sup>24</sup>Again I say to you, it is easier for a camel to pass through the eye of a needle than for one who is rich to enter the kingdom of God.”
>   <sup>25</sup>When the disciples heard this, they were greatly astonished and said, “Who then can be saved?”
>   <sup>26</sup>Jesus looked at them and said, “For human beings this is impossible, but for God all things are possible.”

Jesus is saying in verse 21 that if you *wish to be perfect*, you ought to sell everything and give to the poor, but the verses that proceed from verse 21 explain how impossible that is for people without God.

The disciples' astonishment and query to Jesus in verse 25 speaks to this, essentially saying, "whoa, nobody's going to do that: does this mean nobody will be saved?" Jesus in verse 26 then specifically states that God will save human beings by performing the impossible task: saving those who couldn't normally be saved because they aren't perfect.

Or as the [New American Bible explains](http://www.usccb.org/bible/mt/19:23#48019023-1):

> Riches are an obstacle to entering the kingdom that cannot be overcome by human power. The comparison with the impossibility of a camel’s passing through the eye of a needle should not be mitigated by such suppositions as that the eye of a needle means a low or narrow gate.

Beyond that, the [Didache](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/0714.htm), an early Christian writing that dates to around the same time as Paul, mentions one of the ways you could tell a false Apostle from a real one:

> Let every apostle that comes to you be received as the Lord. But he shall not remain except one day; but if there be need, also the next; but if he remain three days, he is a false prophet. And when the apostle goes away, let him take nothing but bread until he lodges; but if he ask money, he is a false prophet.

It wasn't until much later that justifications for tithing were formulated: the [Catholic Encyclopedia mentions](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/14741b.htm) the first serious attempts to tithe dated to around 567 CE and 585 CE with the Councils of Tours and the Maçon, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Here Jesus confirm the tithe in the NT:

> **Matthew 23:23 KJV**
>   Woe unto you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites!
>   for ye pay tithe of mint and anise and cummin, and have omitted the
>   weightier matters of the law, judgment, mercy, and faith: *these ought
>   ye **to have done**, and not to leave the other undone*.

And here, author of Hebrews explains whom receives that tithe:

> **Hebrews 7:8 KJV**
>   And here men that die receive tithes; but there **he
>   receiveth them**, of whom it is witnessed that he liveth.

Another aspect is, in the Melchizedek era, **before the law**, Abraham gave the tithe Melchizedek, impling that that "rule" is transcending from laws.

Comment: I thought someone would quote these words of Jesus. But these are written to men *under the Law*, not to Christians.

Comment: The second quote is recording the [author of Hebrews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorship_of_the_Epistle_to_the_Hebrews) words about Melchizedek: I don't think there is any doctrinal statement on tithing here.

Comment: @Wikis: author of Hebrews - fixed.

Comment: @Wikis: The author is doing a parallel between Jesus and Melchizedek. Here, he is speaking about "of whom it is witnessed that he liveth": Jesus.

Comment: The quotes here are appropriate, but little or no context is given - for example, the Matt 23:23 is clearly about Jews, not Christians (scribes and Pharisees).  Hebrews is also written to Jews, but in this case specifically Jewish Christians.  It's hard to follow the final point or relate it directly to the quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

Tithing is not a Christian teaching, Christ never taught it even though there are instances where He could have. The apostles never taught it! It is an Old Testament teaching which the church has and is still using to produce money. Tithing is under the law, we are not under the law but under grace. Read Hebrews chapters 7-9 and you will see that we are not in the Levitical times or have a priest. Jesus is from the tribe of Judah which did not participate in that law.

There were a couple of instances where Jesus could have taught tithing. The first was when He was in the temple and watching the offering, He said the woman who gave her all (which was two mites), gave more than all of them because they gave of their abundance; now, if it was about tithing then if the woman would have given just one mite she still would have given more because it would have been a 50% tithe. Second, when the rich man said he had done all and Jesus said one that you are lacking is to sell all that you have and give to the poor and you will have riches in the kingdom -- notice that Jesus didn't say sell all that you have give the 10% tithes and the rest to the poor, He said give it all and you will have riches in heaven. This is not for Christians because there were no Christians at that time!

Answer (score -1):

Is simple impossible that the original church established by Jesus and Apostles have requested Tithing to it's members.
Why?
Very Simple.

The Levites Where a Life and in exercise of their functions under the law of Moses in those early days!

So asking for tithing will have been to violate their rights. The original members were also Jews.

This is why the church only asked for donations. But the real missionaries like Paul, worked with their own hands to provide for himself.
Remember the one in Salarie, do not worry about the sheep but their salary.

Comment: Welcome to C.SE.  I'm sorry to say, I just don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Sometimes Paul worked to support himself, sometimes he relied on the financial support of others. He said in 1 Tim 5:17-18 that Christian workers should be paid. So although you're right that money can be a distraction from godly ministry, being supported can help protect you from the distraction of worrying whether you'll be able to feed your family.

Comment: Paul did work with his own hands in one city, but he also received gifts, particularly from the Philipian Church.

Comment: What I have been trying to say is that in the early Church of Jesus, the apostles would not be able to collect tithes. Why? Because the Levites where in full exercise of functions. so try to do so will be usurping levites rigths will be a sin against the Traditions of the Jewish nation, all early christian were Jews, Until Paul started to Convert Gentiles. and He does not mention the Use of tithing in His writtings, on the contrary, He defended the principle of no Moses law for gentiles. Lets hope is more readable now.